# VBA code to transpose one multiple data column into several columns

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have a list of 65000 rows of stocks price for one column, and I would like to adapt it like in the second pic, anyone has any idea how to code it with vba ? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the data structure is always the same (12 months of data and 3 rows for data set id's). Change Sheet Name on Code Line 9 to suit your Sheet Name

`Sub TRANSPOSE_DATA()
Dim lRow, i, x As Long
'------------------
With ThisWorkbook
'ADD OUTPUT WORKSHEET
    .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count) 'add a sheet for output
    .ActiveSheet.Name = "OUTPUT" 'sheet rename
'COPY DATA
    With .Sheets("Hoja1") 'Change sheet name for yours
        lRow = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row 'last row definition
        .Range("A1:B15").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT").Range("A1") 'First dataset copy (including headers)
        x = 3 'first iteration column definition
        For i = 16 To lRow - 14
            .Range("B" & i & ":B" & i + 14).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT").Cells(1, x) 'copy data from each iteration
            x = x + 1 'transpose 1 column for next iteration
            i = i + 14 'transpose 12 months plus header rows for next iteration
        Next i
    End With
End With
End Sub`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was completely lost with this one.. it really helped me understand

Comment: i'm glad i could help. i added some tags to make understanding each line easier. sorry if my english is not that good.